# Running Batch File in background when windows boots up and execute a format

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, startup, hard-drive

How do I run a batch file each time windows boots up also I need to run it in the back ground  I use Windows 7. My actual requirement is I want to check if the user type 10 times the password to login the program runs a format to the hard disk.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To run it hidden you can use a VBScript (save as `.vbs` file)

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\batchscript.bat"), 0, True
```

To run on startup you can use the registry to launch the vbscript, which will in turn launch your batch file in the background on startup.

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v "Script" /d "C:\script.vbs" /f
```

As per my comment though, I have to ask why you would want to format their hard drive if they get the password wrong, why not a simple 'You have entered the wrong password too many times' message?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is really nice your help. About why i need format the hard drive is because in the company where i work every employee has a important data from the company so my boss wants if the laptop is stole or loss the person who has it the laptop tries to access after 10 times execute the batch to format and maintain hidden the information.

Comment: No worries, that actually makes sense, but you should just encrypt the data instead, if the password is in the batch file or stored in plain text on the laptop then this would be pointless as they could take out the hdd and use it somewhere else. Look at something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org) to encrypt the HDD.

Comment: You can also add the vbs file to the Startup folder to save editing the registry. Start > All programs > Startup > Right click > Open